# How to split number with their signs from text

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to split numbers with signs from a text. I'm use Regex. For example i have this equation:

> 12X-3Y<=-6

In the code below, you can see what I've done:

```
string[] numOfConstraint = Regex.Split(richTextBox2.Text, @"\D+");
```

but this code only split numbers from the other characters. i.e:

> 12 3 6

I want these number with signs.

> 12 -3 -6

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're pretty close, just use `\d` instead of `\D`, capture the `-`, and use Regex.Match instead of split:

```
(-?\d+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

## Usage

```
var match = Regex.Match(pattern, input);
if (match.Success)
{
    foreach (var g in match.Captures)
    {

    }
}
```

You could string those `Captures` together like this:

```
var s = string.Join(" ", match.Captures
    .Select(c => c.Value)
    .ToArray());
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Qi0-IjxwKIclHr2e)

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like this:

```
string text = @"12x-3y<=-6" ;
Regex rx = new Regex( @"-?\d+(\.\d+)?([Ee][+-]?\d+)?") ;
string[] words = rx
                 .Matches(text)
                 .Cast<Match>()
                 .Select( m => m.Value )
                 .ToArray()
                 ;
```

which yields

```
words[0] = "12
words[2] = "-3"
words[4] = "-6"
```

Easy!

The regular expression should match any base-10 literal. It can be broken down as follows:

```
-?              # an optional minus sign, followed by
\d+             # 1 or more decimal digits, followed by
(               # an optional fractional component, consisting of
  \.            # - a decimal point, followed by
  \d+           # - 1 or more decimal digits.
)?              # followed by
(               # an optional exponent, consisting of
  [Ee]          # - the letter "E" , followed by
  [+-]?         # - an optional positive or negative sign, followed by
  \d+           # - 1 or more decimal digits
)?              #
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> strList = new List<string>();
List<float> fltList = new List<float>();
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 for(int i = 0; i < richTextBox.Text.Length; i++)
 {
  if(!char.IsDigit(richTextBox.Text[i]) && richTextBox.Text[i] != "-")
       {
        if(sb.ToString().Length > 0)
            strList.Add(sb.ToString());

        sb.Clear();
       }
   else
       sb.Add(richTextBox.Text[i]);
   }

  float numOut;
  foreach(string num in strList)
  {
    if( float.TryParse(num, out numOut) )
        fltList.Add(numOut);
  }
```

Not the prettiest but it should work.